# How to passing Repeater Row ID to javascript/jquery and change image

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

What I'm trying to do is:

I have a table (repeater) that shows me the various sessions. In each session I can calculate your expenses. For this I have the linkButton **lnkGenerate**.
After expenses are generated automatically changes the image, and becomes **lnkDelete**. (this is done in ascx.cs)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" OnItemCommand="rpt1_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr style="color: Black; white-space: nowrap;">
                <th style="width: 90%">
                    Session
                </th>
                <th style="width: 10%;">
                    Session Value
                </th>
                <th style="white-space: nowrap;">
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr id="row" runat="server">
            <td align="left" style="white-space: nowrap">
                    <%# ((Session)Container.DataItem).Name %>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <%# ((Session)Container.DataItem).ValueSession > 0 ? ((Session)Container.DataItem).ValueSession.ToString() : "-" %>
            </td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGenerate" runat="server" ToolTip="Generate" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="showImg(this);"
                    CommandName="generate" Visible='<%# ((Session)Container.DataItem).ValueSession == 0 && !this.IsBlock %>'>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgGenerate" runat="server" ToolTip="Generate" SkinID="imgGenerateAuto" />
                </asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" CausesValidation="false"
                    CommandName="delete" Visible='<%# ((Session)Container.DataItem).ValueSession > 0 && !this.IsBlock %>'>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgDelete" runat="server" ToolTip="Delete" SkinID="imgDeleteAuto" />
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
```

What i want is:

Clicking on the image to generate the costs, it changes to an image of "**loading**" and then they are calculated, go to **lnkDelete**.
I've tried using javascript, however, each line has a specific ID can not I get.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out my previous proposed solutions, I've decided to rewrite the answer from the scratch.
I created a new project here on VS and tested the code below. It's a simplified version of what you have, but it will work just as expected:

**1) Note that you won't no longer need the OnClientClick event attached.**

**2) Just define the CssClass to your LinkButton and attach a handler to the click event.**

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".linkButton").on("click", function (e) {
                // As I don't have any code running on the code behind, 
                // it would replace the image and return to the original 
                // one pretty quick, so I'm stopping the postback.
                e.preventDefault();                     

                $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://www.bedlingtonterriersfc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/ball-50x50.png");

                return true;
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>

<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptr_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton CssClass="linkButton" CommandName="cmd1" runat="server">
            <asp:Image runat="server" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="http://static.miniclipcdn.com/images/awards/store/32_50.png" />
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: The problem is that I needed to change the image before it generates costs. Cannot be server-side, but javascript / jquery.

Comment: But change it at some event, like click?

Comment: In linkButton "lnkGenerate" i have onclientclick.

Comment: I changed "var showImg(obj) = function ()" to " var showImg = function (obj)". I tested but dont change the image.

Comment: Err... That piece of code I've posted, you should add to a JS file and embed on the page header, or simply add to the page within a script tag. The OnClientClick script stays the same as before.

Comment: I have in my JS File and dont change the image.

Comment: I've changed slightly the selector to find the image related to the link (parent). You can debug the JS file to see if it's doing alright.

Comment: Sorry for the time. But this is a asp:image, dont have "src" only have ImageUrl.

Comment: But it should work just fine, because when rendered, the ASP.NET control will become a regular HTML object.

Comment: Sorry but cant understand why in my case doesnt work. Will the "SkinId" trumps "imageurl"?

Comment: Now you got me. I'm not sure. Maybe someone else can answer then.

Comment: Im debugging with "FireBug" and when i click in the image, dont go to javascript function.

Comment: A fairly easy task is turning to be a pain. LOL Would you mind posting the code generated for this specific page? So we can have a look on the "pure" HTML and see what's going on. BTW, as you're using Firebug, does it throw any exception (JS)?

Comment: Sorry but i solved the problem! lol ... The problem was the version of jquery ... omg .. thank you so much!

Comment: Fair enough. I'm glad you got it sorted out. :) You're welcome.